# Get Validation Attributes in an MVC3 Editor Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I'm writing an editor template for entering a date and time which is made up of three fields.

- A textbox with a jQuery UI datepicker.
- A textbox for entering the time.
- A hidden input that is updated with the complete date and time string through javascript.

The idea is to have separate fields for date and time displayed to the user, while there is only one field that is bound to the model. Whenever the displayed fields are changed, the hidden field is updated through JavaScript.

```
@model System.DateTime?
<span class="datetime-editor">
<input class="datepicker" value="@(Model.HasValue ? 
  Model.Value.Date.ToString() : string.Empty)" readonly="readonly"/>
<input class="time" value="@(Model.HasValue ? 
  Model.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString() : string.Empty)"/>
@Html.HiddenFor(d => d)</span>
```

The JavaScript to set up the datepicker and copy the values to the hidden field.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
$(".datetime-editor").find("input").change(function () {
    var date = $(this).parent().find(".datepicker").val();
    var time = parseTime($(this).parent().find(".time").val());
    if (date != "" && time != null) {
        $(this).siblings(".datetime-result").val(date + " " + time);
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(".datetime-result").val("");
    }
});
```

My problem is the validation attributes. They are all present in the hidden input tag:

```
<input name="StartDateTime" id="StartDateTime" type="hidden" 
  data-val-required="Start date and time are required" data-val="true" value=""/>
```

I would like to somehow grab the generated `data-val*` attributes and add them to the visible inputs instead.  Through `ViewData.ModelMetaData` I can find out if the field is required or not, but then I would have to reinvent the logic to create the `data-val-required` attribute. I would like to get the generated attributes instead.

Comment: I don't see the point of your 2 input fields. They don't have names. Their values will never be sent to the server. Why do you need them? I see that the first is readonly. What validation do you want on a readonly field?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I'm using JavaScript to copy the complete date and time values to the hidden input (see my update).

Comment: so you need validation on the second field as the first is readonly? What kind of validation more precisely do you need?

Comment: The first field is readonly to prevent the user from entering a date manually, but it will be updated when the user selects a date from the date picker. If the `DateTime` field in the model is e.g. marked as `[Required]` I would like both the first inputs to have a `data-val-required` attribute. Somewhere there is logic to create a `data-val-required` attribute if the model meta data has `IsRequired=true`. I would like to reuse that logic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use an HTML helper to generate those inputs if you want HTML5 data-* validation attributes on them:

```
@{
    var validationAttributes = Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("");
}
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Date.ToString() : string.Empty, 
    new RouteValueDictionary(validationAttributes) 
    { 
        { "class", "datepicker" }, 
        { "readonly", "readonly" } 
    }
)

@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString() : string.Empty, 
    new RouteValueDictionary(validationAttributes) 
    { 
        { "class", "time" } 
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! The `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` was the method I needed but couldn't find.

Comment: Returns an empty count to me. Why?

Comment: @IsaacLlopis, is your view model decorated with validation attributes?

Comment: Yes. There are validation attributes that are pre-set and custom validation attributes, but all inherit from existing validation attributes.

Comment: @Darin wOw O_O. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar; the IDE really leads you astray here.

If you want to know if a property on a Model is required, you're sometimes not asking for the `[Required]` attribute, but whether it's Nullable. For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int? Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

Both of these will use EditorTemplates\Int32.cshtml

In your editor template you can use:

```
@model System.Int32?
<input id=@Html.IdForModel() @(Model is Nullable ? "" : "required") />
```

Note that the question mark after `@model System.Int32` (making it nullable) is necessary if  you don't want the IDE to complain when checking `is Nullable`.

Comment: Good edit it by Anders; (off-topic) it's weird that I can't upvote the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should register an adapter to provide client-side validation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.registeradapter(v=vs.98).aspx